# Pouchdb document id complex key

Tags: pouchdb

I know views can be built using complex keys (an array basically).

But, do normal documents also support that? I want to avoid views as performance on phones can be very slow with many many docs. So I'm using the "Use and abuse your keys" approach.

So that is why I would need complex keys so I can use `startkey` and `endkey` on those.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it's totally possible.  Read [this blog post](http://pouchdb.com/2014/06/17/12-pro-tips-for-better-code-with-pouchdb.html), skip to "use and abuse your doc ids."

Basically what you do is use the [PouchDB Collate](https://github.com/pouchdb/collate/) plugin to serialize your complex key into a string, and then use that for the `_id`. Then lookups work exactly the same as with the `query()` API, using `startkey`, `endkey`, `keys`, whatever you like.

Comment: My doubt with this post http://pouchdb.com/2014/05/01/secondary-indexes-have-landed-in-pouchdb.html is.. it is possible to query all albums from a given year on that schema? i mean, no matter its artists, do just 1 query, and get all albums from year 1972, for example?

Comment: In that example, no.  The year would have to be the first element.  In that case you would need a secondary index (view).

Comment: Secondary index are prohibitive on my case: so many documents. So... i'm stuck on this thing...

Comment: You could build two separate databases with different indexes; that's what PouchDB does under the hood anyway for the secondary index. Otherwise if you have many different dimensions that you want to sort on, secondary indexes are the only way...

Comment: I didnt understood that option on many dbs... can you elaborate?

Comment: E.g. build a database where the documents are ID'd by [year, artist] and another one where they're keyed on [artist, album] (or whatever). Although at this point you've kind of re-written persisted map/reduce, so it's probably a bad idea; sorry for suggesting it.

Comment: @nlawson i am confused using collate.  How i will get docs when i do collate with some fields like title/subject  & trying to get docs which has some text 

Here is my try [link] http://jsbin.com/maxoyomasa/edit?html,js,output

Explain me where i am missing! (or) for this case secondary index alone is the solution?

Comment: Hi @raja.s, it seems your mistake is that you should do `allDocs({keys: pouchCollate.toIndexableString("my title")})`, not `allDocs({keys: "my title"})`

Comment: Thanks for your time @nlawson. I have tried but vain. i have created a gist for the same, you can check it in http://bl.ocks.org/joshongit/a0a232fab9a83ce5ef7b  &  https://gist.github.com/joshongit/a0a232fab9a83ce5ef7b   (you can add comment there too)

Comment: Hi @raja.s, I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what you're trying to show me in your Gist. StackOverflow might not be the best venue for this. If you go to the #pouchdb channel on IRC freenode, there are usually many people who are happy to help and guide you through these problems. :)

Comment: Actually wait, I think I see the issue. When you query, you are doing `key:pouchCollate.toIndexableString(keyVal)`, but when you create a document, you set the `_id` to `pouchCollate.toIndexableString([newObj.title,newObj.subject])`. Are you sure that `keyVal` is exactly the same as `[newObj.title,newObj.subject]`? Is it an array? Does it contain two strings? If you are unsure, omit the `key` parameter and look at the output, which will contain `key` objects that contain exactly the key you need. Then you can compare to see what's different about your own `key`.

Comment: Thanks @nlawson i will check and follow IRC channel :)

Comment: Hi @raja.s, I responded on IRC. In case you missed it, see the logs at https://botbot.me/freenode/pouchdb/2015-08-13/ and my corrected version of your Gist at http://bl.ocks.org/nolanlawson/a44ccf92338fa9593e03