# Abuse pouchDB's doc ID: Get first prefix element

Tags: javascript, database, key, pouchdb

Here are some example ID's:

```
someText_1
someText_2
someText_3
someOtherText_1
someOtherText_2
```

I would like to get the "someText"-element with the highest numerical value after the underline: someText_3

```
allDocs({startkey: 'someText_', endkey: 'someText_\uffff'});
```

Would result all "someText_"-elements.
Is there a way recieve only "someText_3"? I want to avoid a map/reduce query, since the guaranteed local storage space is quite limited.

I already read:

http://pouchdb.com/2014/05/01/secondary-indexes-have-landed-in-pouchdb.html (When not to use map/reduce)

[Pouchdb document id complex key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717454/pouchdb-document-id-complex-key) (which has the same problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot search "inside" a string with P/CouchDB _ids - you can only do prefix searching. And of course, prefix searching does not fix your integer problem, because in terms of strings, `1 < 10 < 2`.

One option is to use [pouchdb-collate](https://github.com/pouchdb/collate) directly. So for instance, your ID could be generated from an object like `[2, 'someText']`. This allows you to easily search for integers above and below a certain value, although the downside is that it makes it difficult to search for `'someText'`.

Another option is to just bite the bullet and use map/reduce or pouchdb-find. If your query needs are complex enough, you might have to.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly as you state it out the pouchdb-collate attempt would invert the problem in my case. Thanks a lot for your time.